# Robocopy only runs first line

Tags: windows, cmd, transfer, robocopy, xcopy

Trying to create a batch file that will backup some of the data fro the server onto my external hdd but robocopy only runs the first line of code then closes the cmd window, any suggestions?

```
 @echo off


robocopy "\\Win-2008srv\wmr47" "\\WIN7LBLMKR\e$\Backup\Monday\WMR47" /MIR /R:5 /W:15 

robocopy "\\\ND-SERVER\Users\" "\\WIN7LBLMKR\e$\Backup\Monday\Users" /MIR /R:5 /W:15 

robocopy "\\Server2008-2\sage\" "\\WIN7LBLMKR\e$\Backup\Monday\Simply" /MIR /R:5 /W:15
```

Comment: \\\ should be \\

Comment: corrected that but it still only runs the top line of code and doesn't continue onto the second line

Comment: Is it possible that you have a `robocopy.bat` or `robocopy.cmd` on your system that is intercepting the invocation of the `robocopy.exe`? What is the output of the `WHERE robocopy` command?

Comment: There is no robocopy.bet or .cmd on the system, if you're asking where the output of the copy is going is, onto an external harddrive connected to the main PC over the network

Comment: Follow th usual debugging tips: run the batch in an open cmd window, temporarily set echo to on and ***see*** what happens or not.